# How can I extract the desired value using the filter function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array object called fullvalue. I also have a string in an array called pushedimg.

I used the filter function here to write the code so that if there is a value that does not match between the value of fullvalue.name and the string of pushedimg, it is put in a variable called filters.

This is what I intended answer.

```
    const fullvalue = [
            {diaryItemId: 138, name: "growthLength", value: "1"}
            {diaryItemId: 141, name: "wormHeadSize", value: "2"}
    ]

    const pushedimg = ["growthLength"]

    const filters = fullvalue.filter((v) => !v.name.includes(pushedimg))

    answer

    filters = [{diaryItemId: 141, name: "wormHeadSize", value: "2"}]
```

However, if the value of pushedimg has one more value of wormHeadSize, the values ​​of fullvalue.name and pushedimg both match, so there should be only an empty array in the filters variable, but two values ​​are entered.

like this code

```
    const fullvalue = [
            {diaryItemId: 138, name: "growthLength", value: "1"}
            {diaryItemId: 141, name: "wormHeadSize", value: "2"}
    ]

    const pushedimg = ["growthLength", "wormHeadSize"]

    const filters = fullvalue.filter((v) => !v.name.includes(pushedimg))

    answer 

    filters = [
            {diaryItemId: 138, name: "growthLength", value: "1"}
            {diaryItemId: 141, name: "wormHeadSize", value: "2"}
    ]

    expected answer 

    filters = []
```

How can i fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to filter out exact matches you can simply do

`fullvalue.filter((v) => !pushedimg.includes(v.name))`

but if you want to do a partial match on the name you need to iterate over the items in `pushedimg` and check each value against `v.name`, then if any match is found use that for the filtering. You can do that like this:

`fullvalue.filter((v) => !pushedimg.some((pi) => v.name.includes(pi)))`

Comment: thank you for help but what do you mean partial match ? can you give me a example?

Comment: @user19476497 The `includes()` method on a string does a partial match. For instance, `'hello world!'.includes('world')` returns true because `'world'` is part of the string. You used the `includes()` method on the string `v.name` but I wasn't sure if you did that because you wanted a partial match or if you meant to use the `includes()` method on the array and mistakenly swapped the operands, so I offered solutions for both scenarios.